# Why does my animation only work in a preview?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view representing a timer. It looks like this...

[image]

[Video with animation...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9CgtcAYG41732RfhI7uJnFYIR5GeLI6/view?usp=sharing)

[Video without animation...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FK5YAqWs0ajD-IXrrA9_7uw-tlUqv_43/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, it has a play/pause button, text for the name, and text for the remaining time. Most importantly, the background represents the percentage of the timer that has elapsed.

**When run in a preview, the animation runs smoothly. When run anywhere else, the background jumps to each interval point with no animation.**

Here is the background shape…

```
struct Meter: Shape, Animatable {
    
    init(widthPercentage: CGFloat) {
        self.widthPercentage = max(0, widthPercentage)
    }
    
    var widthPercentage: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { widthPercentage }
        set { self.widthPercentage = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // create the shape…
    }

}
```

Here is the timer view....

```
struct TimerRow: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var timer: ReusableTimer
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Meter(widthPercentage: CGFloat(timer.progress))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .opacity(0.20)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 0.01))
            HStack {
                // Other views...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the preview...

```
struct TimerRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerRow(timer: ReusableTimer(name: "Timer1",
                                      duration: 10,
                                      timeInterval: 0.01))
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 50))
    }
}
```

Notice that the animation duration in TimerRow is set to match the interval of the timer in the preview.

Here is only relevant parts of ReusableTimer...

```
class ReusableTimer: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    let id: Int

    let name: String

    @Published private(set) var counter: TimeInterval = 0
            
    var isRunning: Bool { timer != nil }

    private var timer: Timer?
            
    let duration: TimeInterval
    
    private let timeInterval: TimeInterval
            
    func start() {

        // ...do some other stuff

        timer = Timer(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.counter += this.timeInterval // increment the counter
            if this.counter >= this.duration { this.removeTimer() }
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
    
    func pause() {
        removeTimer()
    }
    
    private func removeTimer() { 
        // Remove the timer 
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share ReusableTimer?

Comment: Done. I added only what I think should be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

90% of the time, I ask the wrong question. My duration gave the appearance that there was no animation taking place, but there was... It was just really fast. So I corrected it to `.animation(.linear(duration: 1))`.

Why did it look perfect in the preview with the incorrect value? That's still a mystery, but it now works.